# Show Row Count in SQL Profiler

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler, rowcount

Is it possible to show a "Row Count" column in SQL Server Profiler?

For example there are CPU and Duration columns but can it show how many rows a query returns?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about using the RowCounts column?

Comment: Yes thanks that's what I was looking for. I did not see the column because I did not click "Show all columns" :)

BTW, here I found this video demonstrating it: http://www.sqlshare.com/media.aspx?vid=829&

Comment: I see my original question was tagged sql-server-2000. I don't think that column was available in that old version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 8):

For **SQL Server 2008 R2**:
From the top menu: Tools -> SQL Server Profiler
Choose the Server name:

[image]

The Trace Properties dialog will appear.
Click on the `Events Selection` tab:

[image: Events Selection]

Click on the `Show all columns` check box
Slide the horizontal scroll bar to the right.
Check the boxes under the column `RowCounts`

[image]

Click `Run`

The trace will start displaying. The `RowCounts` column will be to the very right.
You can drag it to the left if you so desire.

Answer (score -2):

Quite simply, no. It's not a measurable in profiler

Comment: That's unfortunate, would have been really helpful to navigate through lots of Profiler entries by looking at a "Row Count" column.

Comment: When you "Show all columns" RowCounts is one of the choices

Comment: @Mike Forman: I did not know of this. Good to use in the future. Thanks

Comment: @Mike Forman: Thanks I must have missed that before. It's indeed useful!

Comment: I see my original question was tagged sql-server-2000. I don't think that column was available in that old version of SQL Server.