BizTalk 2020 WCF-Sql Polling Receive Location no Response
I have a BizTalk 2020 CU5 Server. It has an application with a receive location polling a Sql Server database running a simple select.
A copy of the database has been moved to another server, for which a connection has been made available over a VPN. A 2nd receive location has been created to connect to the new database. By using Sql Profiler, we can be sure that the polling statement is reaching the new database. However, it seems no results are reaching BizTalk.
The event log on the BizTalk application server shows no errors. I've enabled all tracking but there's nothing in the tracking DB.
I've been assured by the network team that port 1433 is open (it must be because I can see the request in profiler).
Any ideas what could be blocking the response returning to BizTalk or what other ports I need to request be opened?

Is there a version difference between two sql servers?

@siggemannen yes, the working sql is 15.0.4410.1 the non-working sql is 16.0.4155.4

Just a guess but maybe it doesn't support new TDS resultset stuff in sql server 2022. Did you try to wireshark on the BizTalk side to compare the TDS flow? It should display when things "die out".

Thanks @siggemannen we will look into that

Did you see that CU6 is out for BizTalk 2020.  It includes "Support for SQL Server 2022"

Did you check the row counts with SQL Profiler? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251858/show-row-count-in-sql-profiler
Also "Support for SQL Server 2022" would mean using that version for BizTalk's own databases.  It shouldn't affect the receive location.

Can you show us your polling SQL statement?  Have you tried running it in SQL Management Studio to see that it is returning a non zero value?

In the end I had to recruit the help of Microsoft support. After a week inspecting Wireshark and many requests to the remote network team for changes it was finally resolved by allowing ports 135 and 40001 access.
The explanation from Microsoft for this was:
"MSDTC and EntSSO is using RPC, where it first needs to connect to RPC endpoint mapper which is port 135 to do handshake and ask for the current port of MSDTC and EntSSO services. The RPC endpoint mapper then needs to answer back which port to use "
